# Can I use a 3-way light bulb in my 60 watt lamp?

Tags: lighting

How does this work? Is there a way to only use 50 watts?

Some Google results were telling me that if you put a 3 way light bulb in a regular lamp, it will default to middle option, or 100 watts in my case.

If so, what are the dangers of putting this bulb into my lamp? I understand that it is more brighter than normal and also more hotter, but what are the actual chances it will catch on fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fixture is only rated for 60 watt bulbs, then as you seem to understand already, anything else could overheat and cause a fire.

The manufacture of the lamp rated it for 60 watts for a reason - material types, distance of bulb, etc.  Usually there is a safety margin built in, so is your lamp going to combust the second you put a 100 watt bulb in it? Probably not, but why risk it?  The only safe thing anyone should recommend is to follow the manufactures directions.